# How to specify which table you want a echo $row function to echo when two columns have the same name?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this is a weird situation but I currently am trying to pull data with a query in PHP from a read-only database across multiple tables, but some of these tables have columns that are named the same thing. For example in the "job" table there is a column I am trying to pull data from that has the column name *Description* but in the other table I am pulling variables from (job_operation) at the same time there is also a *Description* column. Is there a way I can specify in an echo function which table I would like the *Description* value to come from?

```
SELECT
job.Job, job.Description, job_operation.Description, job_operation.Job_Operation, 
FROM
job, job_operation 
WHERE
job_operation.Job = job.Job AND job_operation.Job_Operation = '$str'
```

Then I would like to specify when I echo the $row *Description* what table it comes from (either the job table or the job_operation table), is this possible?

```
<?php echo $row-> Description; ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use an alias in the sql query so that they don't have the same name to begin with. Then you don't need to worry about the php

Comment: Use an `alias` `select job_operation.Description as JO_DESCRIPTION...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to specify the table from which you want to retrieve the "Description" column value when echoing it in PHP. You can achieve this by using an alias for the column in your SQL query and then referencing that alias in your PHP code.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to accomplish this:

```
    <?php
// Execute your SQL query
$query = "SELECT job.Job, job.Description AS job_description, job_operation.Description AS job_operation_description, job_operation.Job_Operation 
          FROM job, job_operation 
          WHERE job_operation.Job = job.Job AND job_operation.Job_Operation = '$str'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); // Assuming you have a database connection object called $connection

// Fetch the result and loop through the rows
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    // Echo the Description values from the respective tables
    echo "Job Description: " . $row->job_description . "<br>";
    echo "Job Operation Description: " . $row->job_operation_description . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT